# In micro service with Event sourcing, should i save command or event into service db or should it be one big db?

Tags: microservices, cqrs, event-sourcing

As question says, whats the best practice for storing commands and event?!
should i store only commands, since commands will generate the events?!

Answer (score 1):

> As question says, whats the best practice for storing commands and event?! should i store only commands, since commands will generate the events?!

Storing only "commands" works in some settings.  For example, if you review what the team at [LMAX](https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/) was sharing about their designs, you'll see that what they were writing into their journals were the *input messsages*.

In their context, they didn't need to worry that the underlying domain model of the process was going to change (that would happen during the daily maintenance window, when everything was quiet), so there was never any question what the state of the system would be after a given sequence of events.

But `event-sourcing` is normally understood to mean saving a representation of the state of the system -- just that instead of overwriting our data structure, we are extending it (think linked list of changes).  The changes we persist tend to be the observable effects of the inputs, rather than the raw inputs alone.

Answer (score 0):

In the Event Sourcing architecture events are source of your state. So you need to store events - the facts recorded in your system.